# How can I specify the regular expression dialect in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

I have a file which is in Java's regular expression dialect:

```
# Prevents matching at the second half of a version number and things like
# 1.16.2 splitting into 1.1 and 6.2
(?<![._\-\d])

(?<sign>-)?

(?<integerPart>\d+(?:,\d+)*)
(
    (?<fractionalPart>\.\d+)?
    (?<suffix>[kKMG%])?

    # Prevents matching at the first half of a version number
    (?![._\-\d])
|
    # Note how this one does _not_ include '.' because we wanted to deal with
    # integers with a period after them. This may change?
    (?![_\-\d])
)
```

IDEA gives me errors on all the groups, saying: "This named group syntax is not supported in this regex dialect".

But when I edit settings for this inspection there is just one checkbox.

Questions:

- What dialect is the default anyway? I'm mildly surprised that it isn't the Java `Pattern` one
- How do I configure this to use Java one? Is there a magic comment I can put in the file to hint at the format which IDEA and maybe even other text editors would recognise?

Comment: What is the file extension/type specified in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: regexp, but I know no more

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-215461) in IntelliJ IDEA. There is no way to change the dialect at the moment.